# Streaming file download through Zuul

Tags: netflix-zuul

We are using Zuul as API Gateway.
When calling the service directly, the download streams fine, however when calling through Zuul it seems to download the file to zuul first and then stream it from there. This becomes for large file downloads especially when running in GB's, file download starts only after entire file is read in Zuul filter, this frces us to use really large heap size and other performance issues.
We debugged the code and looks like problem happens during

```
private void writeResponse(InputStream zin, OutputStream out) throws Exception {
    byte[] bytes = buffers.get();
    int bytesRead = -1;
    while ((bytesRead = zin.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        out.write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.post.SendResponseFilter.
That loops over untill entire file is read. I tried sending the request as /zuul/...
but nothing helped, please let me know if there is a way out ? we are totally stuck.
We are using "Dalston.SR2" release.

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution, this will disable buffering the file in Zuul side http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_uploading_files_through_zuul

Comment: A link is useful but please post the relevant information for the OP, not just a link, as if the link goes dead so does your answer. Thanks!

Comment: No that solution is for file upload and we are trying download...but we tried that solution but no luck :-(